JDK version not showing in Android Studio settings
When I open Android Studio settings I cannot see the JDK version. No one has listed this problem before, so I am struggling to find a solution. Whenever I have seen screenshots of other people of the settings page, they have the ability to change the Java version there, but for some reason, I don't even have the options other people have. I just updated my Android Studio version.

Would be helpful to specify the Android Studio (complete) version details and your platform/OS. Also, please mention which exact setting entry/feature you're accessing or describe your process for viewing the JDK version. And lastly, please, verify that your JDK installation alone is at least operational.

Firstly You check your java version is the ok ?? you type javac -version in Command line Intrepeter.Then you can see your java version but not show the java version you firstly install the java version
if you have not issue in the java download you must to check the java verion in Android Studio settings and the java version you have installed in the lap.. If the two version do not match you should install the java versiion related to android studio settingss in the lap

thanks. When I type java - version into terminal in android studio i get this message:
java version "1.8.0_411"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_411-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.411-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

when I type java - version into the CMD from windows i get the exact same version.

Have a look at this screenshot of settings. It does not look right to me.
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ao00-W21cZdkkZBZ1wRrb8onnFPwOQ?e=HIlDGP
